# Handling Remote and Local Browsers

Tags: robotframework

I have three keywords which are **RemoteFifox**, **RemoteChrome**, and **LocalBrowsers**

The remote keywords are used when i run my test headless in our Jenkins server.
I hate having to constantly commenting out each script when I want to run them remotely. I would like to implement a Run keyword and IF ELSE.

I currently have

```
*** Keywords ***
I open browser
    [Arguments]  ${BROWSER}
    Run Keyword If  ${BROWSER} =='rFireFox'  remoteFireFox
    ...  ELSE IF   ${BROWSER} =='rChrome'  remoteChrome
    ... ELESE  LocalBrowsers
```

However, I keep getting below error

```
Evaluating expression 'rFireFox =='rFireFox'' failed: NameError: name 'rFireFox' is not defined nor importable as module
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Robot lets you treat robot variables as python variables with expressions by omitting the curly braces. This is described in the section [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the [BuiltIn Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) documentation (see "Using Variables" in that section)

```
Run Keyword If  $BROWSER =='rFireFox'  remoteFireFox
```

Another choice would be to set the variable to the keyword itself, so you could do something like this:

```
Run keyword  ${BROWSER}
```

... and then define `${BROWSER}` on the command line to be the keyword you want to run:

```
robot --variable BROWSER:remoteFireFox
robot --variable BROWSER:remoteChrome
robot --variable BROWSER:LocalBrowsers
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double quote both ends of the comparison

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    I open browser    rFireFox

    
*** Keywords ***
I open browser
    [Arguments]  ${BROWSER}
    Run Keyword If  "${BROWSER}" =="rFireFox"  remoteFireFox
    ...  ELSE IF   "${BROWSER}" =="rChrome"  remoteChrome
    ...  ELSE  LocalBrowsers

remoteFireFox
    Log To Console    remoteFireFox    

remoteChrome
    Log To Console    remoteChrome  
    
LocalBrowsers
    Log To Console    LocalBrowsers
```

Comment: The weird thing is When It try to execute the If Else portion I get error: expected 0 arguments, got 2.. If I flip the keywords I around I still get the same error.